# How to execute multiple commands on machineB from machineA efficiently?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, scp

I have a tar `(abc.tar.gz)` file in my `machineA` which I need to copy and untar it in my `machineB`. In my `machineB`, I have an application running which is part of that tar file so I need to write shell script which will do these below things on `machineB` by running the shell script on `machineA` -

- execute command `sudo stop test_server` on `machineB`
- delete everything inside `/opt/data/` folder leaving that tar file.
- copy that tar file in `machineB` inside this location `/opt/data/`
- now untar that tar file in `/opt/data/` folder.
- now execute this command `sudo chown -R posture /opt/data`
- after that execute this  command to start the server `sudo start test_server`

In `machineA`, I will have my shell script and tar file in the same location. As of now I have got below shell script by reading the tutorials as I recently started working with shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

readonly SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION=/opt/data
readonly MACHINE_LOCATION=(machineB) # I  will have more machines here in future.
readonly TAR_FILE_NAME=abc.tar.gz

ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo stop test_server'
ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo rm -rf /opt/data/*'
sudo scp TAR_FILE_NAME david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]}:$SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION/
ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'tar -xvzf /opt/data/abc.tar.gz'
ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo chown -R posture /opt/data'
ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo start test_server'
```

Did I got everything right or we can improve anything in the above shell script? I need to run the above shell script in our  production machine.

Is it possible to show the status message for each step, saying this step got executed successfully so moving to next step otherwise terminate out of the shell script with the proper error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it all in a single `ssh` round-trip, and the tarball doesn't need to be stored at the remote location at all.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

readonly SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION=/opt/data
readonly MACHINE_LOCATION=(machineB)
readonly TAR_FILE_NAME=abc.tar.gz

ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} "
    set -e
    sudo stop test_server
    sudo rm -rf '$SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION'/*
    tar -C '$SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION' -x -v -z -f -
    sudo chown -R posture '$SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION'
    sudo start test_server" <"$TAR_FILE_NAME"
```

This also fixes the bugs that the tarball would be extracted into your home directory (not `/opt/data`) and you lacked a dollar sign on the interpolation of the variable `TAR_FILE_NAME`.

I put the remote script in double quotes so that you can use `$SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION` inside the script; notice how the interpolated value is interpolated in single quotes for the remote shell (this won't work if the value contains single quotes, of course).

You could perhaps avoid the `chown` if you could run the `tar` command as user `posture` directly.

Adding `echo` prompts to show progress is a trivial exercise.

Things will be a lot smoother if you have everything -- both `ssh` and `sudo` -- set up for passwordless access, but I believe this should work even if you do get a password prompt or two.

(If you do want to store the tarball remotely, just add a `tee` before the `tar`.)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it looks much better. I cannot run this shell script as `posture` user since these two commands `sudo stop test_server` and `sudo start test_server` I cannot execute with `posture` user as I can only execute with `david` user so that's why I am doing it like this. I know I can modify `/etc/hosts` file to add those two command to be run by that `posture` user but the problem is that file will get overridden by puppet since that is what managing our system in production. I hope you understood what I was trying to say.

Comment: One more thing, Is there any way that I should type my password only once at the command prompt and after that it should reuse same password for all the commands, instead of typing my password everytime?

Comment: Of course you cannot run root commands as `posture` but perhaps you could `sudo -u posture tar zxvf ...`

Comment: And no, I have no idea how modifying `/etc/hosts` would allow you to run privileged commands as another user.  Maybe you mean  `/etc/sudoers`?

Comment: `sudo` by default remembers your password for a few minutes.  For `ssh`, look into using `ssh-agent` and/or passwordless keys (less recommended).

Comment: Yeah sorry I mean to say `/etc/sudoers`. Messed up the name. I can try with `sudo -u posture` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate status message for each step using exit status of ssh command like I tried with first two ssh command.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

readonly SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION=/opt/data
readonly MACHINE_LOCATION=(machineB) # I  will have more machines here in future.
readonly TAR_FILE_NAME=abc.tar.gz


# An error exit function

function error_exit 
{
  echo "$1" 1>&2
  exit 1
}


if ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo stop test_server'; then 

echo "`date -u`     INFO    : Stopping test_Server" 1>&2

else
  error_exit "`date -u`     ERROR   : Unable Stop test_Server! Aborting."

fi



if ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo rm -rf /opt/data/*'; then 
    echo "`date -u`     INFO    : Removing /opt/data" 1>&2
else
    error_exit "`date -u`   ERROR   : Unable to remove! Aborting."

fi

    sudo scp TAR_FILE_NAME david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]}:$SOFTWARE_INSTALL_LOCATION/
    ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'tar -xvzf /opt/data/abc.tar.gz'
    ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo chown -R posture /opt/data'
    ssh david@${MACHINE_LOCATION[0]} 'sudo start test_server'
```

Password management you can create ssh pass-wordless authentication.
http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html